# Reading common contacts from firebase database and phonebook

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBB5G.png)

I am building a tracking application where a user can select a follower from their phonebook who can then track their journey.So to implement this,I(user) has to access their phonebook and select the contacts who they would like to send a follow request. For this, I want my application to show only the contacts who have the app installed. I have created a user class to store the details of the users in the firebase database.I am able to access the contacts from my phonebook. Also,I am able to store the details of the people who are using my application in firebase database. When I am trying to retrieve the phone numbers of the users from the firebase database, it does not give me the result as expected. Can someone help me in this regard?

I have created a Main activity which has Firebase database in it. When a new user registers their details are fed into the Firebase database. The structure of my firebase looks like this:
    contactsfirebase-16ade

> ```
>  users
>    -LiNCTO6eR2TVmKmJXLE
>       email: "kira_6809@yahoo.com"
>        name: "kiran"
>       phone: "1234567890"
> ```

In the next activity, for trial I have added a button and a ListView such that when I click on the button,I should be able to see all the details of the users present in the firebase database.I have shared below the code that I am using for all of this.

MainActivity:

```
EditText Name,Email,Phone;
Button Submit,Load;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Name= findViewById(R.id.Name);
 Email= findViewById(R.id.Email);
 Phone= findViewById(R.id.Phone);
 Submit= findViewById(R.id.Submit);
 Load= findViewById(R.id.Next);
 databaseReference=
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    AddUser();
  }
});

Load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowFirebase.class));
  }
});
}
private void AddUser() {
String name = Name.getText().toString().trim();
String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
String phone = Phone.getText().toString();
User user = new User(name,email,phone);
String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
if((!name.isEmpty())&&(!email.isEmpty())&&(!phone.isEmpty())){
  databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user);
  Toast.makeText(this,"Registered successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowFirebase.class));


}else{
  Toast.makeText(this,"Retry",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

ShowFirebaseActivity:

```
public class ShowFirebase extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView ListView;
Button Load;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_firebase);
    ListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    Load = findViewById(R.id.Next);
    databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference phoneref = databaseReference.child("phone");

    //String id = databaseReference.getKey();


    Load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            databaseReference.child("users");
            databaseReference.child("id");
            databaseReference.child("phone");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : 
dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String number = ds.getKey();
                        numbers.add(number);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numbers);
                    ListView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }
    });

}
```

}

User Class:

```
public class User {
String Name,Email,Phone;

public User(String name, String email, String phone) {
Name = name;
Email = email;
Phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
return Name;
}

public String getEmail() {
return Email;
}

public String getPhone() {
return Phone;
}
}
```

There is no error in the code as such, but when we are clicking the button in the ShowFirebase Activity, the only thing that is showing up is the text "users". I expect to see all the phone numbers present in the firebase database.

Edited:

```
public class ShowFirebase extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView ListView;
Button Load;
String phoneNumber;
String name;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_firebase);
    GetNumber(this.getContentResolver());
    ListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    Load = findViewById(R.id.Next);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String number = ds.child("phone").getValue(String.class);
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                numbers.add(number);
            }
            numbers.retainAll(aa);
            ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
            ListView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
private void GetNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC");
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        System.out.println("......." + phoneNumber);

        aa.add(name + " " + phoneNumber);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the screenshot in the Firebase Database Structure link at the beginning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
            databaseReference.child("users");
            databaseReference.child("id");
            databaseReference.child("phone");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : 
dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String number = ds.getKey();
                        numbers.add(number);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numbers);
                    ListView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

into this:

```
            databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String number = ds.child("phone").getValue(String.class);
                        numbers.add(number);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numbers);
                    ListView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Add a reference to node `users` then iterate inside the `userid` and retrieve the `phone` value.

Comment: I have another issue now. I am trying to compare the Array List retrieved from firebase database with the phonebook contacts stored in another Array List that I have so that I can find the common contacts via phonenumber. I have implemented the code for that in the manner that I have added under Edited section. However, the Listview remains empty instead of displaying the common contacts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have another question it is better to ask another question, but please add the required information, and code in your question with screenshot of your database.

Comment: Okay will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
reference = 

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pets").child(fireba 
  setUser.getUid());
     reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : 
dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String key = childSnapshot.getKey();


                }


          @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError 
   databaseError) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "onCancelled: 펫이미지 가져오는데 문제 발생! 
    ");  
        }
    });
```